# rxjava complete after retryWhen on completeable

Tags: rx-java2, reactivex

I'm using the retryWhen operator on a Completeable, is there a way to tell it to complete from the retry Flowable?
something like this -

```
PublishSubject<?> retrySubject = PublishSubject.create();
public void someFunction() {
    someCompletable.retryWhen(new Function<Flowable<Throwable>, Publisher<?>>() {
        @Override
        public Publisher<?> apply(Flowable<Throwable> throwableFlowable) throws Exception {
            return throwableFlowable.flatMap(throwable -> retrySubject.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.MISSING));
        }
    }).subscribe();
}

public void ignoreError(){
    retrySubject.onComplete();
}
```

Comment: Why do you flatMap onto a subject instead of using a `PublishProcessor` directly? You don't seem to need the actual throwable.

Comment: It's just an illustration to my source implementation, in my source implementation the retry is based on the error type so I need to flatmap. it's just seemed irrelevant to the question so I dropped it out of the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't stop a `flatMap` by giving it an empty source. Also every error will keep subscribing more and more observers to that subject that causes memory leak.

Use `takeUntil` to stop a sequence via the help of another source:

```java
PublishProcessor<Throwable> stopProcessor = PublishProcessor.create();

source.retryWhen(errors -> 
    errors.takeUntil(
        stopProcessor
    )
    .flatMap(error -> Flowable.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
)

stopProcessor.onComplete();
```

**Edit** If you want to reuse the same subject, you can suppress items on the stop path:

```java
PublishProcessor<Integer> stopProcessor = PublishProcessor.create();

source.retryWhen(errors -> 
    errors.takeUntil(
        stopProcessor.ignoreElements().toFlowable()
    )
    .flatMap(error -> stopProcessor)
)

// retry
stopProcessor.onNext(1);

// stop
stopProcessor.onComplete();
```

Comment: I would also want in my ViewModel to call - public void retry(){retrySubject.onNext(new Object())} to be able to trigger the retry, how would I do that without a retry subject?